# Aren't $S_\infty$ and $T_\infty$ same here?

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals, contest-math

The following question was asked in JEE 2008.

**Question:**

Let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2}$ and $T_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2}$ for $n=1,2,3,...$ Then,

A) $S_n\lt\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}$

B) $S_n\gt\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}$

C) $T_n\lt\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}$

D) $T_n\gt\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}$

**Solution:**

$S_n\lt S_\infty=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x+x^2}=\frac2{\sqrt3}\left(\tan^{-1}\frac{x-\frac12}{\frac{\sqrt3}2}\right)_0^1=\frac2{\sqrt3}\left(\tan^{-1}\frac1{\sqrt3}-\tan^{-1}\frac{-1}{\sqrt3}\right)=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}$

Thus, option A) is correct.

Also, $T_1=1\gt\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}$

Thus, D) option is also correct.

**Doubt:**

$T_{\infty}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n}{n^2+kn+k^2}=\int_0^1\frac1{1+x+x^2}$

Is this correct?

Doesn't this give us $T_n\lt\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}?$

Comment: Do you understand why $S_n < S_\infty$?

Comment: @JBL looks like I hadn't really understood it. But wih the posted answer, things are clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $f(x)=\frac 1{1+x+x^2}$, we have
$$ S_n=\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^nf(\tfrac kn)$$
and
$$ T_n=\frac 1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(\tfrac kn)$$
so both give an estimate for $\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx$.
The difference is that $S_N$ uses the right ends and $T_n$ the left ends of the $\frac1n$-intervals.
Since $f$ is strictly decreasing on $[0,1]$, this means that $S_n$ under-estimates and $T_n$ over-estimates the integral, i.e.,
$$ S_n<\frac \pi{3\sqrt 3} <T_n.$$

---

Note that  $T_n-S_n=\frac 1n(f(0)-f(1))$ gives you a hint how good both approximations are.

Comment: Thank you very very much!